# difference between Liebe Güte and ach je

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between *Liebe Güte* and *ach je*?
Both are translated as *oh god* or similar to that. So I never heard it before from any German. What do they mean and in which context can we use them?

Comment: why downvote, I've searched and not satisfied what's wrong with my question then?

Answer (score 1):

**Liebe Güte**!  Exclamation of terror or amazement.  Colloquially.  The word "Güte" here stands for god (**Gott**).
Mostly used **ach du liebe Güte** or **ach du meine Güte** as phrase unpleasant surprise.

**Ach je** expresses regret or terror. Example: „Ach je, das tut mir leid“ (What‘s the matter with that).

I hope that clarifies your question

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what SwissCodeMen said:
Ach du meine Güte can be a reaction to pure horror news. 
But if the news are not e. g. life threatening horror,  the exclamation can also have the connotation of - more or less suppressed - amusement.

When e. g. it's about someone you have sympathy for and you feel sorry for; but at the same time there is also an entertaining amusing aspect in it that makes you suppress a smirk. 
=> Ach je  / Ach du meine Güte = also as reaction to a tragical yet also comical/gossip-worthy situation

In this case:
Ach je as a less strong expression, demonstrates a more calm reaction, resignated or matter-of-fact (think of it as the follow-up of a sigh) 
Ach du meine Güte demonstrates a more lively mood, and indicates the speaker's clear sympathy for but also his mild amusement about the person in question.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is about word usage, an addition: "Liebe Güte" or "Meine Güte" is frequently used sarcastically or ironically to indicate that something, despite appearances, is not actually a big deal, or that one considers somebody else's reaction over-the-top.